# Get order by id and customers that made the order

Tags: magento-1.8, orders, customer, database

I have following task to do (I have 0 magento experience, and I am told to do this):

Make standalone script that reads every order from Magento, and filter those that have purchased this product id => 297. Then write the customer and order information into a csv file on the server.

I know how to make CVS file, but I don't know how to work with magento. 
How can I do this?

Comment: Why does it have to be a stand alone script?

Comment: There is custom backend, that is independent from magento, and this script will be the part of synchronization between two DBs - magento and backend. CVS script will be imported via function from the backend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
<?php
 
require_once('app/Mage.php'); //Path to Magento
umask(0);
Mage::app();
 
$productId = 297;


$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();
$orders
     ->getSelect()
     ->joinInner(array('order_item' => Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('sales/order_item'), 'order_item.order_id = main_table.entity_id' ))
     ->where('product_id=?', $productId)
     ->group('main_table.entity_id')
     ->order('main_table.entity_id DESC');


foreach($orders as $order){
     // create csv file here
     //$order->getData();
     $order->getIncrementId()
     $billingAddress = $order->getBillingAddress()
     $shippingAddress = $order->getShippingAddress()
}
```

See [Exporting order details magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19922563/exporting-order-details-magento)

Comment: I am getting this error:Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Item (Mage_Sales_Model_Order) with the same id "12"

Comment: Add `->group('main_table.entity_id')` see update

Comment: Didn't have time yesterday to thank you :). The code is working :)